# how to resolve stack memory overflow error in java

Tags: java

i am creating a utility to call web service which retrieves data from database according to current date.For that i am creating a service() method which call recursively if any new data will inserted into database on current date.but that code will through's stack overflow error after some period of time

```
package com.RMCServices;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import dbconnection.DbCon;

public class SimpleThreadPoolRMC {



    public SimpleThreadPoolRMC() {
        processCommand();
        try {
            finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Service();
    }

    public void Service(){
        Connection con=null;
        con=DbCon.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps1=null,ps2=null;
        ResultSet rs1=null,rs2=null;
        String phone_no=null;
        try {
            ps1=con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(d.id) AS id,d.Batch_No,d.tcontractor_id,d.twork_id,d.Batch_Time,d.Production_Qty,SUM(d.Gate1_Actual)AS Gate1_Actual,SUM(d.Gate2_Actual) AS Gate2_Actual,SUM(d.Gate3_Actual) AS Gate3_Actual,SUM(d.Gate4_Actual) AS Gate4_Actual,SUM(d.Cement1_Actual) AS Cement1_Actual,SUM(d.Water1_Actual) AS Water1_Actual,SUM(d.Adm1_Actual1) AS Adm1_Actual1,SUM(d.Adm2_Actual1) AS Adm2_Actual1,r.Truck_No,r.Recipe_Name FROM tr_rmc_batch_details AS d,tr_rmc_batch AS r WHERE d.tContractor_Id=r.tContractor_Id AND d.tWork_Id=r.tWork_Id AND d.tPlant_Id=r.tPlant_Id  AND d.Batch_Date='2015-12-31' AND d.status_check='0' AND d.Batch_No=r.Batch_No GROUP BY d.Batch_No limit 1");
            rs1=ps1.executeQuery();

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            while(rs1.next()) {

                ps2=con.prepareStatement("SELECT nPhNo1 FROM ct_contractor_info WHERE tcontractor_id='"+rs1.getString("tcontractor_id")+"' AND SUBSTRING(service_type,1,1)='1'");
                rs2=ps2.executeQuery();

                while(rs2.next()){
                    //phone_no=rs2.getString("nPhNo1");

                    Runnable worker = new WorkerThreadRMC(rs1.getString("id"),rs1.getString("Batch_No"),rs1.getString("tcontractor_id"),rs1.getString("twork_id"),rs1.getString("Batch_Time"),rs1.getString("Production_Qty"),rs1.getString("Gate1_Actual"),rs1.getString("Gate2_Actual"),rs1.getString("Gate3_Actual"),rs1.getString("Gate4_Actual"),rs1.getString("Cement1_Actual"),rs1.getString("Water1_Actual"),rs1.getString("Adm1_Actual1"),rs1.getString("Adm2_Actual1"),rs1.getString("Truck_No"),rs1.getString("Recipe_Name"),phone_no);
                    executor.execute(worker);
                }
            }
            executor.shutdown();
            while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(rs1!=null){
                rs1.close();}
                if(rs2!=null){
                rs2.close();}
                if(ps1!=null){
                ps1.close();}
                if(ps2!=null){
                ps2.close();}
                if(con!=null){
                con.close();}
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Finished all threads");

        new SimpleThreadPoolRMC();
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         new SimpleThreadPoolRMC();  
     }
}
```

please give me some valuable solution on that.

Comment: on a sidenode, if you use java 1.7+ i´d rather go with `try-with-ressources` instead of using the `finally` way to close the connections.

Comment: I'm the first to admit that threads complicate things for me.  Whenever I have problems with programs using threads, the first thing I absolutely must do before proceeding is to verify that the program works *without* threads.  If you don't have problems that way, then you know it may be a concurrency issue or something of that sort.  Just eyeing it, you're loading every child of a parent record in memory by appending it to a job to run.  If you had several million records, I don't know if I'd be so confident that you could hold it all.

Comment: First I would work out which error you mean? Is it a StackOverflowError or is it an OutOfMemoryError?  Where is this error happening, i.e. when you look at the stack trace?

Comment: The line which appears in your stack trace is most likely the last one in your constructor which shouldn't be calling itself as that doesn't make sense. If you would like to confirm this is a bug, I suggest you use your debugger.

Comment: This might be induced by you infinite recursive calls (hence you get an infinite stack of methods called in methods). If you call your method externally (e.g. with a `while(true)` in Service) instead, you'll solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks something like

```
public class SimpleThreadPoolRMC {

    public SimpleThreadPoolRMC() {
        // sleeps 5s
        processCommand();
        // call service method
        Service();
    }

    public void Service() {
        // build a threadpool, and run it for a particular query 
        // ...

        // gratitious recursion!
        new SimpleThreadPoolRMC();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleThreadPoolRMC();  
    }
}
```

your stack is therefore constantly growing until you get an exception. Use this instead:

```
public class SimpleThreadPoolRMC {

    public SimpleThreadPoolRMC() {
       // if no initialization performed, leaving this empty is ok
    }

    // changed name to lowercase
    public void service() {
        // build a threadpool, and run it for a particular query 
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleThreadPoolRMC simple = new SimpleThreadPoolRMC();
        while (true) {
            // sleeps 5s
            simple.processCommand();
            simple.service();
        }
    }
}
```

The new version is equivalent, but uses iteration instead of recursion, and your stack should no longer explode.